# Matlab - fixed text size when zooming

Tags: matlab, text, plot, zooming

I wish to keep the text size fixed when zooming in a plot. Thus I wish to specify the position of the 4 corners of the text-area. To explain it in other words: When the plot is zoomed out the text should hardly be visible because it is so small. Is this possible? It should be but I have not seen any solution.

As for now I am plotting a circle

```
rectangle('Position',[xpos, ypos, 0.06, 0.2], 'Curvature',[1,1]);
% I wish to plot textstrings of num2str(val) inside the circle here
% Another alternative, to be able to se num2str(val) whenever I click the circle
```

Thanks in advance

/fixitinthemix

Comment: Your code so far could help you get an answer.

Comment: Added my code to plot circle

Comment: The standard behaviour is to keeping the text size after zooming....  Maybe you are wishing the opposite. To rescale the text when zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `FontUnits` property on the text handle to make the text scale with the axes. See [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html) for the different possibilities.

Comment: Have you got around to trying this out?