# How to plot text with a fixed size

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting text with matplotlib, when zooming in and out the text size stays the same.

However, I want to plot the text with a fixed size relative to the plot. This means that when I zoom in, I want the text to get bigger; likewise, when I zoom out, I want the text to get smaller.

I found this same question but it is for Matlab instead of Matplotlib in Python: [Matlab - fixed text size when zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585729/matlab-fixed-text-size-when-zooming)

This seems trivial yet I have not been able to find a solution. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Still have not received an answer, but I'm still looking.

EDIT2: I found another question on stackoverflow that is essentially the same as this one. He did get one response that said to "plot the path by hand", yet I do not know what that means. [Text object in matplotlib doesn't respond to zooming properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305754/text-object-in-matplotlib-doesnt-respond-to-zooming-properly)

Comment: The "plot the path by hand" refers to using the whole Matplotlib API (vs the matplotlib.pyplot module). The pyplot module (often shown in code samples as "plt") is a collection of simplified functions that do common tasks. These functions hide much of the details, thus they are good for exploration, but not for complex tasks.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Do you know of any resources or tutorials of how to plot the text with a fixed size with the Matplotlib API?

Comment: Under "[Creating a new scale]"(http://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html?highlight=limit_range_for_scale#creating-a-new-scale), it states you will need to subclass `matplotlib.scale.ScaleBase` with a Formatter.  I've never done this before, but you can see [custom_scale_example.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html?highlight=zoom) to get started.